# connection to server through socket io client

Tags: node.js, windows, sockets

I created an server application in Node js using express, socket.io. I am able to connect server application from browser via socket.io client. I want my application to access within the home network and my colleagues are able to connect to my application with my IPV4 address but socket io connection is not working. I manuaaly set my IPV4 address in there socket io connection.

Node js:

```
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var app = express();
var http_server = require('http').createServer(app);
var cors = require("cors")
var io = require('socket.io')(http_server)


io.on('connection', function(client) {
    console.log('Client connected...');

    client.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log("Client disconnected..");
    });
});


var server = http_server.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log("app running on port.", server.address().port);
});
```

HTML code:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
   var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
      socket.on('connect', function() {
          console.log("server connected..");
      });
</script>
```

How to mention in Html code to connect to my server..??

I tried google and various responses from stackoverflow but nothing helpful..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer..

HTML Code:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
var ipAddress = 'http://localhost:3000';
<script>
   var socket = io.connect(ipAddress);
      socket.on('connect', function() {
          console.log("server connected..");
      });
</script>
```

I changed the `ipAddress` from `localhost` to my `IPV4 address`. It works fine once i restart server and my colleagues can access my application in their computer.